# How to write out a line to the default HTML reporter in Playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-typescript

I am using the default HTML reporter in Playwright.  I would like to write out some custom text to the default reporter in the Test Steps Section.  What is the command to do this?  I am not seeing it off the page object.

Currently this line does not appear in the Test Steps section but instead appears in the Attachments.stdout

```
console.log("Begin Order Workflow")
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find something of use here.
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-reporter

Annotations are key/value pairs accessible via test.info().annotations.

The HTML reporter will show Annotations that are added to tests.  So in a test you could add this line:

```
test.info().annotations.push({ type: 'issue', description: 'descriptive text' });
```

Comment: Dan, this is interesting.  It puts it in a separate Annotations block before the test steps in the reporter.  The goal is to log statements in the Test Steps section.